# Need subreport to share main report date range parameter - C1 Designer

Tags: vbscript, componentone

Entered the following vbscript into the TEXT field of the subreport header on the Main report as instructed.

```
"[Time Charge Date] = '" & [Time Charge Date] & "'"
```

Subreport only produces records that equal the date of the LAST record of the Main Report.  Confirmed this by changing dates on the last record, subreport records followed suit.

Unable to use Main report WHERE statement in the subreport data source. (error)

Trial and error syntax testing futile.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share the main report date range parameter with the subreport you can update DataSource.RecordSource of the subreport in script event, for example you can put following code in the Report.OnOpen script of the master report:

```
fldSubReport.Subreport.DataSource.RecordSource = "select * from Orders where OrderDate between #" & [Start Date] & "# and #" & [End Date] & "#"
```

Please click [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B715FADFBBDA44CC!4896&authkey=!AL2NW99ZDMQIuck&ithint=file%2Cxml) to download the sample report ("sample.xml") demonstrating the above implementation.

Note: Sample.xml uses C1NWind.mdb database.

Comment: Is there someone I can talk to about this?  I am unable to convert the recommended syntax to my application and I'm not sure where the problem is.